# Create new dense column in Pandas Dataframe by joining together two sparse columns

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

I have a dataframe with three columns, 'Name of Organization', 'Type' , 'Type of Org'. 'Type' and 'Type of Org' are the same thing. I want to create a new column named 'Org Type' that takes the string in the 'Type' column, and if the 'Type' column is blank, takes the name in the 'Type of Org' column.

```
Example of current dataframe:
Name of Organization     Type      Type of Org     
Tyco                     Retail    Retail          
Mac                      Service
Lis                                Comm
Ice                      Tech
Rex                      Retail    Retail


Example of New dataframe: 
Name of Organization     Type      Type of Org    Org Type
Tyco                     Retail    Retail         Retail
Mac                      Service                  Service
Lis                                Comm           Comm
Ice                      Tech                     Tech
Rex                      Retail    Retail         Retail
```

Essentially I am trying to join together the 'Type' column and the 'Type of Org' column in order to create one complete column as both columns are missing some data but the data they do have will be the same. If there is a better way to do these, i would love any suggestions- just not sure what the best way to approach this issue is? a while loop?

Comment: If a string is in both columns for the same row, is the string always the same?

Comment: @ Charles Morris - Yes

Comment: `df['Org Type'] = numpy.where(df['Type'], df['Type'], df['Type of Org'])`

Comment: @Paul H Okay so this is does work- thank you very much. Only problem is I actually lied. There seems to be a few where the string in 'Type' is not the same as the string in 'Type of Org'. So what the code is doing is actually creating an additional row for those instances. so my count of names of organization is going up.

Comment: df['org_type'] = np.where(df['Type'], df['Type'], df['Type of Org']) or df['org_type'] = np.where(True, df['Type'], df['Type of Org']) give the desired output. If any row has two different values, the value in df['Type'] takes precedence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to set the `Org Type` column to the `Type` column before subsetting on those rows which are missing. If the `Type` column contains missing values (not just empty strings), the following should do the trick. If it does contain empty strings or similar, you can subset on where the `Type` column is equal to those values.

```
df['Org Type'] = df['Type']
df.loc[df['Org Type'].isnull(), 'Org Type'] = \
    df.loc[df['Org Type'].isnull(), 'Type of Org']
```

Comment: @3Novak- this also works however having the same issue as above. Because in a very few cases, the data in 'Type' and 'Type of Org' is not the same, I need to prioritize the data in 'Type'. This code is increasing my count in names of organizations by creating another row for each time there are two different strings in 'Type' and 'Type of Org'.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, you should accept @Boud's answer. It should do exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 3):

This feature is called [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df.Type.combine_first(df['Type of Org'])
Out[332]: 
0     Retail
1    Service
2       Comm
3       Tech
4     Retail
Name: Type, dtype: object
```

Comment: @Boud- This is great and is simple. But i still dont understand why my original org count is 154 and my new count is now 163... There are org ids which are listed twice within the 154. Do you think python is somehow duplicating?

Comment: Not sure to understand your problem, could you elaborate? Otherwise if it's 150 lines just just dump the two results, open them like in Excel and compare manually. You'll quickly find what s different and identify the pattern